# Filtering columns where all rows match a specific value in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a dataframe like so:

```
Apple   Orange  Strawberry
0           1       1
0           1       1
0           1       0
0           1       0
0           1       0
0           1       1
0           1       1
```

I want to filter the dataframe such that I get the column names where all the rows are a specific value say `0`.
In this case I would get `Apple`

I tried doing

```
df[rowSums(df<1)==0, ]
```

but I'm just getting an empty dataframe with all the column names. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: you need `colSums` and not `rowSums` eg `names(df)[colSums(df) == 0]` or even `names(Filter(all, df==0))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
names(df)[colSums(df) == 0]
```

or even

```
names(Filter(all, data.frame(df == 0)))
[1] "Apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(where( ~ sum(.) == 0)) %>% 
  names()
```

**Output**

```
[1] "Apple"
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Apple = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Orange = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Strawberry = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```